# Account verification Yelp style, how is it more "secure" than traditional verification?

Tags: email, verification, user-accounts

For business owners to "take control" of their business page on Yelp, they register for it.

The Yelp system performs a telephone call-back. From [watching to the video here](http://www.yelp.com/business/unlocking), it sounds like a telephone version of what we all typically do - e-mail check.

**For e-mail check, it basically goes like this:**

User registers > verify e-mail sent > they click link inside verify e-mail > site verifies

**Here's Yelp's:**

User registers > verify screen shown with code > Yelp calls user > user enters code > site verifies

It's essentially the same thing, via phone. **Is there any reason you can see why this method is better than the e-mail method?**

**Update:**
I assumed the reason Yelp called was to make sure the person registering was indeed the owner of the business. But watching the video, that isn't the case. It looks like typical validation - telephone style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can create fake email accounts that are hard to trace, while it's significantly harder to have a phone # that is fake/untraceable (doable but orders of magnitude less so)

Comment: Hmm... interesting. But, essentially the verification is combat the wrong owner taking ownership of a business page, correct? The phone call back wouldn't prevent that any more than an e-mail verification. Though I understand what you're saying, I don't see it making it anymore "safe".

Comment: It doesn't necessarily prevent up-front fraud technically, but it makes it MUCH simpler/more reliable to trace afterwards and as such, both prevents fraud up-front (i'll go scam someone who's less likely to catch me and requires less efforts) AND increases the post-factum verification

Comment: ok, I buy it. It is definitely more difficult to fake a phone number than an e-mail address. Do you think it's necessary to be able to trace back to the person impersonating the owner? Or simply be able to remove what the impersonator did, and put the owner in control?

Comment: I'll take an easy out and say "both" :)

Comment: Touché! :D  Let's say the only trace back you can offer is to the e-mail, info that was entered... and then offer to remove it all immediately and give the real owner full control. Do you believe there's major issues with that?

Comment: That depends on the amount of damage it can cause real owner, and how good the real owner's lawyers are :)

Comment: Do you think the terms in the site's terms of use can protect a website that only offers e-mail verification as described above? :D

Comment: true enough... this isn't the forum for these questions anyway. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the game I *think* the key point is Yelp calls the phone number they already have for the business.

So in order to get around that, you'd either need to have access to that businesses telephone at the time of the validation call, or, edit the phone number with your own, get it approved somehow then go through the validation check.

I've always wondered what a business owner does if the phone number listed isn't correct.